# Is there a term, preferably informal, for upper-tier white collar workers?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, finance

I'm looking for an informal term to describe investment bankers, big law corporate lawyers, high-end consultants, and the like. The closest I can come up with is "yuppie", but that's no good because 1) it refers only to young people, and 2) it's somewhat dated.

Example: They met at a ritzy lounge frequented by [word]s.

Comment: Is “The 1%” too high?

Comment: This is exactly what came to my mind first. @tyler, are you thinking of the super-rich? Or is that secondary to your question? (Would somebody who won the lottery count?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no word specifically limiting to those categories.

You could call them corporate elite. Or just prefix any word with corporate in front.

Comment: Unfortunately I think you're right

Answer (score 0):

In some contexts, *the bourgeoisie* can mean the rich and wealthy who have power over poor people.

Comment: Not bad, but in my mind the bourgeoisie would also include artists, journalists, doctors, and generally a wider array of people than the corporate finance kind I'm thinking of

Comment: Affluent? They met at a ritzy lounge frequented by the affluent.

Answer (score 0):

I would call them 'elite'.

***elite***

NOUN

1treated as singular or plural 
A select group that is superior in terms of ability or qualities to the rest of a group or society.

(https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/elite)

Answer (score 0):

Although, you have requested for noun. I'd suggest an adjective **Eminent**.

According to [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/eminent)

> (of a person) famous and respected within a particular sphere.

Your Example: `They met at a ritzy lounge frequented by` **Eminent** *people*.

I will also request you to check all the example sentences provided on [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/eminent). Few of them are as follows:

1 .  "**It was also patronized by eminent scientists, corporates and intellectuals.**"

Here, [patronized](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/patronize) can be used as follows:

> Frequent (a shop, restaurant, or other establishment) as a customer.
>
> > "restaurants and bars regularly patronized by the stars were often crowded with paparazzi."

2 . "To find answers this programme gathered together a group of eminent people from a variety of backgrounds."